# Lock Down Linux SSH Users

Tags: linux, ssh, security, samba

I am wondering if there is a simple way to restrict ssh users accesses so they can only cd to only three directories.

/tmp

/home/UserID

/opt/apps

It would also be useful if we could remove functions on other directories from these users such as rm out side their home dir.

The server is running RHEL 6.6 and winbind so the users that I want to restrict are all AD users.

Comment: For the most part, the important bits should already be inaccessible to average users. There's not likely to be any need for this overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how secure you need it you can use chroot to make users believe that their home directory is the root directory. Then you can set up the home directories with links to the directories that you want them to have access to (or in the case of /tmp just let them create their own /tmp in their home directory. Two notes:

1. This can be tricky if programs need access to things outside of their own directories and it is not truly secure.
2. Processes that know they have been chroot'ed (including smart users) can get out if they try but it will keep the average user from doing something stupid and wiping out stuff that could be a pain to recover.